# JQuery Multiselect not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have this source of [html](http://jsfiddle.net/prime/QJKB9/)

The problem is though I set 2 options as selected it only shows it sets the last one. No matter how many I set selected it only set the last one.

Why is that ?

```
[1](http://jsfiddle.net/prime/Lp7e7/)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the multiple attribute on the select element:

```
 <select id="businessFn" name="businessFn"  style="width: 225px" multiple>
         <option value="1"  >one</option>                          |________Here
         <option value="2" selected ='selected' >Two</option>
         <option value="3"  >Three</option>
         <option value="4" selected ='selected'  >four</option>
         <option value="5"  >five</option> 
 </select>
```

Comment: Accepting the answer is the best way to say thanks :)

Comment: sure.. :) But it says I have to wait several minutes before accepting. Don't know why :(

Comment: I think it provides other users a chance to answer first

Comment: may be. :) now they allowed !!